# Keep XPtr for multiple sessions

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a R function that creates a `Primebase` Cpp Class and then returns a `XPtr<Primebase>` pointer.

As the construction process takes a significant amount of time I'd like to save the instance of `Primebase` to my session, so that the next time I open up R I can directly access the `Primebase` instance.

Unfortunately the underlying Object gets deleted as soon as I close R and the `XPtr` turns into a `null pointer`.

Is there a way to prevent R from deleting the object or any other way to save the underlying object?

Comment: Build a package. Compils/installs once, is available for the next session, can be shared with others.

Comment: Ate you talking about the object file created during compilation or an object/instance created at runtime?

Comment: I am talking about an instance created at runtime and not the package. Lets say I do myPrimeBase <- createPrimeBase(). After saving the session, closing and reopening R, the variable myPrimeBase is now a null pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ object that is managed by `Rcpp::Xptr` is destroyed when the R session ends. If you want to save the object, you have to serialize it. One nice possibility is offered by the [Rcereal](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcereal) package. The following example uses a trivial `Primebase` class with an artificial sleep in one constructor to simulate heavy processing during the construction. After checking the object's content, it is serialized and destroyed. Afterwards the object is deserialized and wrapped into an `Xptr` again. Note that deserialization is much cheaper than construction:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(Rcereal)]]
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

class Primebase
{
private:
  int x;

public:
  Primebase() : x{0} {};
  Primebase(int x_) : x{x_} {std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));};

  int answer() {return x;}

  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar)
  {
    ar(x);
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<Primebase> create(int x) {
  Primebase* instance = new Primebase(x);
  return Rcpp::XPtr<Primebase>(instance);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
int answer(Rcpp::XPtr<Primebase> xptr) {
  return xptr.get()->answer();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void mySerialize(Rcpp::XPtr<Primebase> xptr, std::string filename) {
  std::ofstream os(filename, std::ios::binary);
  cereal::BinaryOutputArchive archive(os);
  archive(*xptr.get());
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<Primebase> myDeserialize(std::string filename) {
  std::ifstream is(filename, std::ios::binary);
  cereal::BinaryInputArchive archive(is);
  Primebase* instance = new Primebase;
  archive(*instance);
  return Rcpp::XPtr<Primebase>(instance);
}


/*** R
system.time(xptr <- create(42))
answer(xptr)
mySerialize(xptr, "test.cereal")
rm(xptr)
exists("xptr")
system.time(xptr <-myDeserialize("test.cereal")) 
answer(xptr)
*/
```

Output:

```
> system.time(xptr <- create(42))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   1.001 

> answer(xptr)
[1] 42

> mySerialize(xptr, "test.cereal")

> rm(xptr)

> exists("xptr")
[1] FALSE

> system.time(xptr <-myDeserialize("test.cereal")) 
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 

> answer(xptr)
[1] 42
```

References:

- [Cereal documentation](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/)
- [Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-serialization/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for!